# Upgrading packages for my Angular application

Tags: angular, unit-testing, webpack, karma-jasmine, package.json

I am trying to integrate Karma and Jasmine for my front end application which is currently on `Angular4` and webpack. Should I upgrade all packages to their latest versions? For example, I am using `webpack1.x`, `typings`, `typescript 2.0.3` etc... Should I upgrade them to `webpack2`, `@types` and `typescript@latest` respectively?

When I look at Angular's `package.json`, i see that they are using `Webpack1.x`. But `webpack1` is deprecated and webpack is encouraging everyone to switch to v2.

Also do all the above mentioned packages go hand-in-hand with respect to their packages; as in, when `typescript2` is used should i use `@types` instead of `typings` and `webpack2` instead of 1.x?

Comment: I would use angular cli. They probably provide a better build procedure than what you have, and maintain the dependencies for you. And if you have to ask that question, you'd better use something simpler than a custom build.

Answer (score 0):

The best option for you to update your dependencies manually is running `npm update`, now I don't believe it is necessary, as Angular will require peer-dependencies to be updated if necessary (and will inform you too!).

Comment: But is it absolutely necessary to upgrade Webpack to V2 considering V1 is deprecated? How long can we continue to use a deprecated package? Also since Angular hasnt updated Webpack, do I have to?

Comment: These have been old dependencies. I have posted new dependecies , where wepback is not a peer dependency

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to know the current dependency structure:

```
{
  "name": "proj",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.3.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.1.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
}
```

and run `npm update` to update to the latest packages your configuration allows.